# How to refresh instance of class if some action in another class was done

Tags: java, swing, variables, actionlistener

I have class DnyMesice what creates many instances of JButton. Every instance contains variable poznamkaDne. This class DnyMesice contains actionListener to find poznamkaDne value of pushed JButton.
I have class Gui what creates one instance of mentioned class DnyMesice and one instance of JTextArea.
How can I refresh value of JTextArea (names poznamkovePole) if some JButton (in class DnyMesice) is pushed?

```
public class DnyMesice extends JPanel {
    public String poznamkaDne="first note";
    jButton tlacitkoDen;

    public void zobrazMesic(Calendar kalendar){
        for (c=1; c<30; c++){
                tlacitkoDen = new JButton(Integer.toString(denvMesici));
                 tlacitkoDen.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
                     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                         poznamkaDne="New note";
                     };
                 });
                 add(tlacitkoDen);
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
public class Gui extends JFrame {
    ...
    public void zobrazKalendar(){
    ...
    panel3 = new JPanel(); 
    panel3.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    add(panel3);

    JTextArea poznamkovePole; 
    poznamkovePole = new JTextArea();
    poznamkovePole.setColumns(30);
    poznamkovePole.setRows(5);
    poznamkovePole.setText(panel2.poznamkaDne);
    panel3.add(poznamkovePole);

    }
```

Now the program shows in JTextArea only "first note" (which is defined during creating of instance JButton) but hot to refresh it after ActionListener action?

Comment: Trying calling `poznamkovePole.repaint()` at the end of the `actionPerformed` method.

Comment: It doesn't work. The class DnyMesice doesn't know the poznamkovePole. It is created in class Gui and class Gui create instance of DnyMesice. Unfortunately ActionListener is in class DnyMesice if it is in same class as poznamkovePole it would be much more easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe better if you will use:

Add to DnyMesice JTextArea link and in ActionListener change text.

```
public class DnyMesice extends JPanel {
    private JTextArea poznamkaDne;
    jButton tlacitkoDen;

    public DnyMesice (JTextArea jTextArea){
        this.poznamkaDne = jTextArea;
    }

    public void zobrazMesic(Calendar kalendar){
        for (c=1; c<30; c++){
                tlacitkoDen = new JButton(Integer.toString(denvMesici));
                 tlacitkoDen.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
                     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                         poznamkaDne.setText("New note");
                     };
                 });
                 add(tlacitkoDen);
        }
    }
}
```

P.S. - And please don't forget to use [Code Conventions for the Java](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconvtoc-136057.html)

Answer (score 0):

Modify as follows:

```
// add these methods
public void setPoznamkaDne(String s) {
    poznamkaDne = s;
}

public String getPoznamkaDne() {
    return poznamkaDne;
}

// CHANGE this method (KEEP the rest of the code!)
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
    setPoznamkaDne("New note");
};

poznamkovePole.setText(panel2.getPoznamkaDne());
```

These changes should allow you to update the text. BUT you need to either call `poznamekovePole.setText()` somehow, or implement an advanced listener class. I recommend combining your class like @Too Strong Magic said, above.